# VuetifyJS: How to make v-stepper-header sticky on scroll

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-stepper

I'm looking for a way to make the `<v-stepper-header>` component sticky on scroll.

I've tried to create custom CSS but didn't succeed.

Here's a sample code.

```
<v-stepper v-model="step">
    <v-stepper-header class="sticky">
        <v-stepper-step
            step="1"
        >
            Step 1
        </v-stepper-step>
</v-stepper>

.sticky {
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove `overflow: hidden` from `v-stepper` class.

```html
<v-stepper class="stepper">
 ...
</v-stepper>
```

and

```css
.stepper {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2ctjnrvu/).

But why? From MDN about [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

> Note that a sticky element "sticks" to its nearest ancestor that has a "scrolling mechanism" (created when overflow is hidden, scroll, auto, or overlay), even if that ancestor isn't the nearest actually scrolling ancestor.

and useful article [Position: stuck; — and a way to fix it](https://uxdesign.cc/position-stuck-96c9f55d9526).

Comment: Awesome! It worked. Thank you for the fix and additional resources.